# Wordpress Site is Broken, Cannot see wp-admin page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-admin

My wordpress site is broken after I tried to reset my site with some plugin called wp-reset.

[image]

I tried below solutions to fix this issue but still not able to see admin dashboard:

1. In phpMyadmin - db, in **options** table I tried to remove **s** from **https** in **home** and **siteurl** field.
2. I have also added **my self** as **admin** from backend in **phpMyadmin** tables.

when I login with my credentials in **wp-admin** the page looks like this with no **admin Dashboard**

**How can I fix this issue? is there any way by which I can upload some wordpress data or could I reset from the backend in my phpMyadmin and do something?**

Comment: did you back up your site before using that plugin? If not then you're out of options, you should contact WP Reset support for help with that plugin and using it. 3rd party plugin support questions are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-reset/